# NZEC Error in CodeChef online compiler (Python 2.7.9)

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve a problem on CodeChef using Python 2.7.9
I get a runtime error (NZEC) when I try to submit the solution, although the code runs as expected in the online CodeChef IDE. I'm a beginner in python and I'm using the following code:

```
# cook your code here
p=input()
k=[]
for x in range(0,p):
    k.append(input())
l=[]
f=int(p-1)
print f
for x in range(0,f):
    lnum=k[x]+k[x+1]
    l.append(lnum)
for w in range(0,f):
    print l[w],
```

Sample Input:

```
5
1
4
2
6
7
```

Sample Output:

```
5 6 8 13
```

The CodeChef problem can be found [here](https://www.codechef.com/COIT1502/problems/CODEIT24).

Comment: What happens if you **run your code**,? All you stated is that it compiles sucessfully, not that it **runs sucessfully**.

Comment: My apologies, the code runs successfully in the online compiler and gives the expected output but while submitting it as a solution, the online checker gives `Runtime Error(NZEC)`

Comment: Could your code expect be input in a different format.

Comment: The question clearly says the input will be integers only:       `Input Format:
The first line of the input is a positive integer N indicating the numbers of integers. The next N lines contains N integers`

Comment: Can the issue be caused due to some boundary case?The question says ` 0 < N < 1000` Although I checked the maximum possible length of a list in Python and it is more than enough for a 1000 list elements.